KSP generated Moshi adapters not used in combination with Retrofit in a kotlin based SpringBoot application
I fail to get serialization to work inside a small springboot application. Read a couple of issues, guides and documentation on this. But still fail to get this to work.
I use moshi for JSON serialization. I prefer codegen over reflexion, but there are still some areas where reflection is required (some external model POJOs I have no control over).
In my gradle file:
plugins {
    // ...
    id("com.google.devtools.ksp") version "2.1.0-1.0.29"
    // ...
}

dependencies {
    // ...
    // Moshi
    implementation("com.squareup.moshi:moshi:1.15.2")
    implementation("com.squareup.moshi:moshi-kotlin:1.15.2")
    ksp("com.squareup.moshi:moshi-kotlin-codegen:1.15.2")
    // ...
}

The (reduced) DTOs:
@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
data class GeocodeRequest(
    @get: [Valid UniqueReferenceConstraint]
    val addresses: List<AddressRequest>,
)

@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
data class AddressRequest(
    @get: NotBlank
    val reference: String,

    @get: NotBlank
    val street: String,

    val houseNumber: String?,

    @get: NotBlank
    val city: String,

    val postalCode: String?,
)

The API:
internal object GeocoderProvider {
    @VisibleForTesting
    var mockApi: Geocoder? = null

    fun get(): Geocoder {
        return mockApi ?: Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(GeoProperties.baseUrl)
            .client(OkHttpClient.Builder().build())
            .addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create())
            .build()
            .create(Geocoder::class.java)
    }
}

interface Geocoder {
    @POST("/geocode")
    suspend fun geocode(
        @Body request: GeocodeRequest
    ): Response<GeocodeResponse>
}

The retrofit client in my test class (identical to the "real" one):
    geocoder = Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(mockWebServer.url("/"))  // Point Retrofit to the mock server
        .client(OkHttpClient.Builder().build())
        .addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create())
        .build()
        .create(Geocoder::class.java)

The request object:
    val geocodeRequest = GeocodeRequest(
        listOf(
            AddressRequest(
                reference = "Rathaus",
                street = "Rathausmarkt",
                houseNumber = "1",
                postalCode = "20095",
                city = "Hamburg"
            )
        )
    )

And finally the actual request:
val response = geocoder.geocode(geocodeRequest)

At runtime I get this (shortened) exception:
Unable to create converter for class <...>.GeocodeResponse
for method Geocoder.geocode
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to create converter for class <...>.GeocodeResponse
for method Geocoder.geocode
[...]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot serialize Kotlin type <...>.GeocodeResponse. Reflective serialization of Kotlin classes without using kotlin-reflect has undefined and unexpected behavior. Please use KotlinJsonAdapterFactory from the moshi-kotlin artifact or use code gen from the moshi-kotlin-codegen artifact.
The (shortened) StackTrace:
at com.squareup.moshi.ClassJsonAdapter$1.create(ClassJsonAdapter.java:98)
at com.squareup.moshi.Moshi.adapter(Moshi.java:146)
at com.squareup.moshi.Moshi.adapter(Moshi.java:106)
at retrofit2.converter.moshi.MoshiConverterFactory.responseBodyConverter(MoshiConverterFactory.java:89)
at retrofit2.Retrofit.nextResponseBodyConverter(Retrofit.java:418)
at retrofit2.Retrofit.responseBodyConverter(Retrofit.java:401)
at retrofit2.HttpServiceMethod.createResponseConverter(HttpServiceMethod.java:137)
at retrofit2.HttpServiceMethod.parseAnnotations(HttpServiceMethod.java:97)
at retrofit2.ServiceMethod.parseAnnotations(ServiceMethod.java:39)
at retrofit2.Retrofit.loadServiceMethod(Retrofit.java:235)
at retrofit2.Retrofit$1.invoke(Retrofit.java:177)
at jdk.proxy3/jdk.proxy3.$Proxy19.geocode(Unknown Source)
at <....>.GeocoderTest$test geocode returns valid response$1.invokeSuspend(GeocoderTest.kt:76)

I can see the adapters generated by KSP, they look fine to me. But they are not used. Looks to me as if moshi tries to create new ones using reflection and fails too (might be the same issue, which I fail to understand).
Anyone got a hint for me? An idea what I miss?

OK, indeed it was, as always, something extremely stupid I missed. Obviously the framework works as expected. I experienced a classical Layer 8 issue ...
Serialization for the request actually worked perfectly. It was the de-serialization of the response that did not work. Why not? I did not tell moshi to generate adapters for those classes.
The error message actually says so (of course):

Unable to create converter for class <...>.GeocodeResponse for method Geocoder.geocode

GeocodeResponse, not GeocodeRequest ...
sigh
